# MYSQL and condição

Tags: mysql, condição

Preciso fazer um select no meu banco de dados igual está abaixo:

```
select 
* 
from tbl_frete f 
join tbl_transportador t on f.idtransportador = t.idtransportador 
join tbl_cliente c on f.idcliente = c.idcliente 
join tbl_situacaofrete s on f.situacaofrete = s.idsituacao 
where f.idcliente = 1 
and f.situacaofrete = 0 
and f.situacaofrete = 1 
order by f.idfrete
```

porém não retorna nada, e quando faço o select assim:

```
select 
* 
from tbl_frete f 
join tbl_transportador t on f.idtransportador = t.idtransportador 
join tbl_cliente c on f.idcliente = c.idcliente 
join tbl_situacaofrete s on f.situacaofrete = s.idsituacao 
where f.idcliente = 1  
order by f.idfrete
```

retorna os dados mas não como eu queria, já que não retorna os fretes com situacao 1

Como faço esse AND?

Comment: No primeiro comando, você está dizendo que quer `f.situacaofrete = 0 and f.situacaofrete = 1`. Tente tirar a primeira parte da condição (`f.situacaofrete = 0`)

Comment: @LeonardoPessoa mas aí os que tem situação = 0 não aparecem

Comment: existem situações de 0 a 3, quero que apareçam as 0 e 1

Comment: exemplo tem bastante ali em baixo, espero que te ajude

Answer (score 2, accepted):

João, como Leonardo falou, você coloca no where a condição do registro ter dois valores ao mesmo tempo, isso sempre irá retornar vazio. Basta tirar uma das condições, ou mudar o operador.

Retirando uma das condições:

```
select 
* 
from tbl_frete f 
join tbl_transportador t on f.idtransportador = t.idtransportador 
join tbl_cliente c on f.idcliente = c.idcliente 
join tbl_situacaofrete s on f.situacaofrete = s.idsituacao 
where f.idcliente = 1 
and f.situacaofrete = 1 
order by f.idfrete;
```

Mudando o operador:

```
select 
* 
from tbl_frete f 
join tbl_transportador t on f.idtransportador = t.idtransportador 
join tbl_cliente c on f.idcliente = c.idcliente 
join tbl_situacaofrete s on f.situacaofrete = s.idsituacao 
where f.idcliente = 1 
and (f.situacaofrete = 0 
OR f.situacaofrete = 1) 
order by f.idfrete;
```

Ou ainda, utilizar o in

```
select 
* 
from tbl_frete f 
join tbl_transportador t on f.idtransportador = t.idtransportador 
join tbl_cliente c on f.idcliente = c.idcliente 
join tbl_situacaofrete s on f.situacaofrete = s.idsituacao 
where f.idcliente = 1 
and f.situacaofrete in (0,1) 
order by f.idfrete;
```

Ou, excluir dos resultados os indesejados:

```
select 
* 
from tbl_frete f 
join tbl_transportador t on f.idtransportador = t.idtransportador 
join tbl_cliente c on f.idcliente = c.idcliente 
join tbl_situacaofrete s on f.situacaofrete = s.idsituacao 
where f.idcliente = 1 
and f.situacaofrete != 2 
order by f.idfrete;
```

Comment: obrigado!!! eu precisava utilizar o in!